# Can the Maverick hat be made a silver badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

It seems that there are no badges similar to the criteria of the [Maverick hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/maverick):

> answer +5 a -3 question that goes to +3

This badge would promote users to answer many underrated good questions.

Would this make a good silver badge?